# No module named agw.aui

Tags: wxpython, python-2.5

Im using python 2.5, while running module persist_handlers.py which i downloaded from http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main im getting a error  No module named agw.au(wx.lib.agw.aui).
How to Install wx package?

Actually I'm trying to pickle a wx.frame using persistencemanager

is there any easier way to pickle this?..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have a recent version of wx. I think the agw library was added in 2.8.9 or thereabouts. You can always download it from SVN though and add it to your system. On my Windows box, it would go here:

C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\agw

The persistence manager just saves and loads settings from widgets. You cannot directly pickle a wxPython widget because it is wrapped around C++ stuff that just isn't able to be pickled. However, you should be able to pickle your settings since those will just be normal Python objects.